# How do I change my Objective-C stacktrace?

Tags: objective-c

I have a situation where my stacktrace is symbolicated, but not to the degree or custom level I'd like it to be.

The specific issue is the base class is displayed instead of the child class. For example:

```
@interface Parent
- (void)test;
@end

@interface Child : Parent
@end
```

`Parent` implements the `test` function. Child does not. When a stacktrace comes my way, the following is presented:

`TestPackage.-[Parent test] ( Parent.m :100)`

I want it to instead state:

`TestPackage.-[Child test] ( Parent.m :100)`

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What benefit do you get from seeing `[Child test]` here when `Child` doesn't actually have a method named `test`? How does it help you debug the app?

Comment: I have several thousand different children classes based off this parent. These aren't handwritten -- they're code-generated based off individual schemas (I'm doing obj-c magic to retrieve fields from these child classes in `test`).

When I see crash logs, it's difficult to debug and tell which child is the culprit.